# asp.net inserting data with " ' " causes exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am inserting data into a .mdf database through a webpage. When I insert words that contain the apostrophe " ' ", it causes an exception. I tried the escape \' but this inserts the whole " \' ". I don't want to insert these directly into the database table through visual studio because I need the Date.Now time/date to be inserted too (through C#).

Please show me how to insert the " ' " and other like characters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Instead of using direct SQL, use SQL parameters. They automatically handles these issues. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AN I think the exception is too obvious: SQL syntax error :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape it with double apostrophe `''`, but you shouldn't use it in `SqlCommand` text. Always add parameters using `SqlCommand.Parameters` to avoid sql injection possibility.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are inserting the data in a way that you should never use. NEVER, NEVER write an SQL command string using string concatenation. Use parameters instead. ie:

Instead of doing this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into myTable (FirstName, LastName) values ('" +
            txtFirstName.Text + "','" +
            txtLastName.Text + "')", connection);
```

Do it like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into myTable 
            (FirstName, LastName) 
            values (@fName, @lName)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", txtFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", txtLastName.Text);
```